# Python : could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, numpy

When I run the code below I get the an error message saying "ValueError: could not convert string to float: ". I have combed through my 1.CSV file to see is there was nay string type data in the columns if there was I deleted those columns. My question is what am I missing in this problem?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('1.csv', skiprows=2, delimiter=',')
time = data[:, 6]
HTR1_Volts = data[:, 24]
HTR2_Volts = data[:, 25]

plt.plot(time, HTR1_Volts, color='red', label="HTR1_Volts")
plt.plot(time, HTR2_Volts, color='blue', label="HTR2_Volts")
plt.ylabel("CO2 (ppm)")
plt.xlabel("Time (sec)")
plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')
plt.grid(color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)
legend_x = 1
legend_y = 0.5
plt.legend(["HTR1_Volts", "HTR2_Volts"], loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(legend_x, legend_y))

plt.savefig('PLOT1.PNG', dpi=600, bbox_inches="tight")

plt.show()
```

Comment: You have an empty column in one of the rows. Make sure you don't have any blank lines.

Comment: Notice that the error is reporting an **empty** string.

Comment: Keep in mind that CSV can *only* store text. A spreadsheet program, when it imports the CSV, may try to make some intelligent guesses about numeric conversions based on what the strings look like. But in a file, everything is just bytes, and the CSV format doesn't really dictate any particular interpretation of them besides treating the data as text and interpreting newlines, commas and quote marks to determine rows and columns.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Comment: AMC : I wish I could if I could attach the 1.CSV file but unfortunately I don't so I can't do anything about it.

Answer (score -1):

As you use literal comma as a delimiter, there is big chance your data is messed up somewhere and got shifted. If so another field is now on your way.

Check if all floating point values are delimited by dot.
Check if there is any comma in all other fields. If so, either escape or delete comma.

This is good practice to use semicolon as delimiter in csv files though.

Comment: Yup had empty columns in my CVS file I deleted those and removed any blank rows from below and now it works Thanks :)

Comment: _This is good practice to use semicolon as delimiter in csv files though._ The better solution is to format the data so as to avoid the issue entirely, and surround values with quotes if necessary.